# Multiple rows to one column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table    A        B
column  key      name
         1       John
         1       Michael
         2       Alice
         2       Josh
```

On my database when i do this query:

```
SELECT A.key, GROUP_CONCAT(B.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
  FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.key = B.key 
 WHERE B.name = 'John'
 GROUP BY A.key
```

**My Output**:

```
  key      name
  1        John
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  key      name
  1        John, Michael
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition specifically excludes getting any result other than `John`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `HAVING` clause to your query which asserts that a given set of `key` records contains the name `John`:

```
SELECT
    a.`key`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) names
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b
    ON a.`key` = b.`key`
GROUP BY
    a.`key`
HAVING
    SUM(b.name = 'John') > 0;
```

Note: `key` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and you should not use it to name your columns (though maybe you only gave it above as an example).

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query

```
select A.`key`, GROUP_CONCAT(B.'name' SEPARATOR ', ') 
from (select `key` from tblB where n='John' limit 1) as A 
inner join tblB B on B.`key` = A.`key`
group by A.`key`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the result containing the name `John`, then the following query with `exists` keyword might be used :

```
SELECT A.key, GROUP_CONCAT(B.name ORDER BY B.name SEPARATOR ', ') as "Names"
  FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.key = B.key 
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE name = 'John' AND B.key = A.key )
 GROUP BY A.key;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a5c99d46b879d8f070cd8c2ab2582193)</kbd>